# Who completed the original binding in the Old Kingdom books?

Tags: old-kingdom

In *Abhorsen*, the conclusion of the original *Old Kingdom* trilogy by Garth Nix:

> Lirael learns how the seven "Bright Shiners" bound the Destroyer in the first place, centuries ago; the person who completed the binding (cutting the metal sphere in half) was killed in the process.

Is there any indication of who this person was? All seven seem to be accounted for:

> Five of them ceased to exist when they formed the Great Charters; Kibeth and Astarael stuck around, and both show up in the same book, so presumably neither one was killed centuries earlier.

And it's clear that someone did die in the process:

> After watching it happen in the vision, Lirael will know that completing the binding will kill her; as far as she knows, the second binding does indeed annihilate Kibeth, so the Shiners themselves aren't immune to it.

So—who was this person? My unfounded guess would be

> Nehima, who is now "long forgotten"; the inscription that appeared on the reforged sword right before the second binding was "Remember Nehima".

But this is speculation, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

Having done some research I can't find a solid answer myself either.

According to the [fandom wiki page on Orannis](https://oldkingdomwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Orannis):

> It's unknown which of the Seven cleaved Orannis in two, and thus died, at the first binding (uncited sources think it was Astarael, as Lirael was standing in for her). It's unlikely this Shiner was fully destroyed, however, as the Nine are essentially immortal. Possibly, Lirael Saw the destructive power she would have to endure and knew she would not survive, though the Shiner probably did in some form.

However I quite like your theory that it could have been Nehima, given the symbolism of Lirael having to reforge Nehima for the job, although having said that [this other SE answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19897/in-the-old-kingdom-trilogy-by-garth-nix-why-do-the-inscriptions-on-certain-swor) points out that Nehima is likely a long forgotten Wallmaker and not a Bright Shiner.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's unclear here who _you_ are asserting completed the binding.  Please note that as an answer this is expected to name someone and provide evidence that person is the subject.  You might want to read [answer].

Comment: @DavidW thanks - I'm familiar with how to answer (I'm on a number of other SE sites and read rather a lot of the answers on this site). It appears that there is no clear answer from the source material, hence the link and direct quote from another source of such information researched by readers of the material. An answer fitting the form of many others on this site including high rep users such as yourself ;)